# Elastic Load Balancer on port 443 works for forced SSL Ruby On Rails application, but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My ruby on Rails application is configured with the following:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

And I set up the following elastic load balancer:

[image]

With this configuration everything works, but I do not understand why? with the code above, my application instance will return a 301 redirect in response to HTTP request. When the HTTP request is handled by the load balancer, it is forwarded on to to the instance as a HTTP request. Shouldn't this result in another 301, and therefore an endless loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
I thought a bit about my answer and decided to get in to some more detail with it.

Network communication is usually composed of several layers, among which are the *physical layer*, which is the cable/radio channel where information travels through, the *transport layer* which is often TCP/IP, the *protocol layer* which in our case is usually HTTP or HTTPS and finally the *application layer* which is what our rails app handles.

Rails usually never gets in touch with the actual HTTPS data stream, as this is handled by your webserver. So how does force_ssl work at all?

The protocol layer is handled by the webserver (nginx, mongrel...) and this is who could care first about forcing ssl. When the webserver hands over a request to the application layer (hence, the rails app), it also provides a lot of meta data, which includes requester IP, request path, request format, a lot of header variables and also information about the used protocol.

When a request arrives at your webserver on port 443 (and uses HTTPS protocol), the webserver sets the header flag `SERVER_PROTOCOL` to `https`.

If a proxy server (like load balancer is) receives a request on 443 and forwards it to 80, it adds the `X-FORWARDED-PROTO=https` header to the request, which is made available for your rails app by the webserver.

Now, long story short: `config.force_ssl` requires `SERVER_PROTOCOL` **OR** `X-FORWARDED-PROTO` to denote `https`.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
The rails force_ssl method does not really force a request to arrive on port 443 on your server, it is satisfied when the original (client) request was sent over ssl through the internet. The load balancer (as a proxy) sets the header X-FORWARDED-PROTO to "https". rails trusts that information and that is why this is working.

More info on that can be found in the elastic load balancer docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-for